# Drive select box with icons in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Is there any windows form control that shows list of drive letters with icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but I'm sure you could make it happen, shouldn't be too tricky, either with a TreeView or if you would just like the list then you could use a ListView.

The code to get the drives would be similar to this:

```
//Get all Drives
DriveInfo[] ListAllDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

To determine the icons for the ListViewItem or TreeViewNodes you could do something like this:

```
foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListAllDrives)
{
    //Create ListViewItem, give name etc.
    ListViewItem NewItem = new ListViewItem();
    NewItem.Text = Drive.Name;

    //Check type and get icon required.
    if (Drive.DriveType.Removable)
    {
    //Set Icon as Removable Icon
    }    
    //else if (Drive Type is other... etc. etc.)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay for this, you could check out http://viewpack.qarchive.org/.

I'm not aware of any free controls.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally came up with my own control.

I fill a listview with drives as follows:

```
listView1.SmallImageList = new ImageList();
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                      .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                      .Select(x => x.Name.Replace("\\",""));
foreach (var driveName in drives)
{
    listView1.SmallImageList.Images.Add(driveName, GetFileIcon(driveName));
    listView1.Items.Add(driveName, driveName);
}
```

Where GetFileIcon is my own method that calls SHGetFileInfo:

```
IntPtr hImgSmall;    //the handle to the system image list
SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
//Use this to get the small Icon
hImgSmall = Win32.SHGetFileInfo(fileName, 0, ref shinfo,
                               (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                                Win32.SHGFI_ICON |
                                Win32.SHGFI_SMALLICON);

return System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
```

Win32 class is copied as is form [this site](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/icons/article.php/c4261) and looks as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SHFILEINFO
{
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public IntPtr iIcon;
    public uint dwAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string szDisplayName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string szTypeName;
};

class Win32
{
    public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
    public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;    // 'Large icon
    public const uint SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;    // 'Small icon

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath,
        uint dwFileAttributes,
        ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
        uint cbSizeFileInfo,
        uint uFlags);
}
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Just a note, watch out when using shell32.dll, it's liable to change (you know what microsoft are like!), I asked a question about using their icons here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949196/loading-icons-from-shell32-dll-win32-handle-is-not-valid-or-is-the-wrong-type