# How can I access to system icons like "folder", "file" etc.?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I would like to use standard icons in treeview but I am not sure where to get them? I tried different places like resources etc., but without luck.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the treeview to show folders/drives/files then your best bet would be to work with the system image list/SHGetFileInfo. This way you get "native" images on all Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 they are held as resources in C:\Windows\system32\imageres.dll

I think older versions of windows had the resources in user32.dll

Answer (score 0):

They are stored as resources in `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial219_Extracting-Icons-from-Files.html) in how to extract the icons in c#.

Also look at this question: [Loading icons from Shell32.dll: Win32 handle is not valid or is the wrong type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949196/loading-icons-from-shell32-dll-win32-handle-is-not-valid-or-is-the-wrong-type)