# Windows 7 Like circular loader?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, controls

i was just wondering if anyone has made anything for C# similarly looking to the circular loading thing used almost everywhere in Windows 7 and Vista.

[circular loading thing http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/3127/a7ff394fb1d04795b9a2a21.png](http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/3127/a7ff394fb1d04795b9a2a21.png)

**Edit:**

Ive noticed alot of comments about *cursors* but that is not related at all to what im trying to do. I am trying to create a loading circle, drawn to my window as a custom control (or something like that.)

**What Ive tried so far:**

Ive attempted to extract the loading images from the following dll `%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll`
with no success, using the link provided by Mark Pim [(this one)](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial219_Extracting-Icons-from-Files.html)

i tried it, and was able to successfully extract ***A*** image from the dll, but i can not determine how to extract the specific image that i need. being the circle animation listed in the dll as `Bitmap/5004`.

here is some code ive tried

```
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, int cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);
    public Image GetImage()
    {
        IntPtr hImgLarge;
        SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO() { };
        string FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll";
        System.Drawing.Icon myIcon;
        hImgLarge = SHGetFileInfo(FileName, 0, ref shinfo, Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), 0x100);
        myIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
        return myIcon.ToBitmap();
    }
```

im not sure how to manipulate the SHGetFileInfo to return the correct image. any ideas?

Comment: You could include the cursor file in your application and draw it to the screen. Why reimplement it in C#?

Comment: The Windows wait cursor is smaller than the circle that im looking for.. but can you even animate a cursor while drawing it to the screen?

Comment: **this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor** delivers the default UI behaviour for Win7. From and UX perspective I recommend to maintain that instead of changing the User-experience on other platforms.

Comment: @Tommy: What about Cursors.AppStarting?

Comment: even if i did want to use a cursor, how would i draw that to the screen while maintaining the animation? Cursor.Draw only shows its starting position.

Comment: i dont see where you guys are all going with the cursor thing. i didnt mention a "cursor" anywhere in my question. im looking draw a loading circle to my Window.

Comment: @Tommy: I think they did that because the place you see that the most is the wait cursor.  There are other places it exists, though, and maybe people don't realize that.  If you can get a screenshot of one of the non-cursor areas, and edit your question to show that you're not looking for the cursor, that might help fish out some better answers (though I tried to match what you were asking in my answer).

Comment: The primary reason we jumped to the cursor conclusion is because that's exactly what that is. Yes, it's used other places as an indeterminate activity indicator, but it's exactly the same thing as the default wait cursor. You said you wanted to draw it yourself, so you have two choices: you try and extract it from the shell (which breaks on older versions of Windows *and* newer versions of Windows that potentially move/reorder items), or you include the animated cursor as a resource in your project and draw it yourself. (For the record, I've seen it used many places. Still the same cursor.)

Comment: @Cody: Are the several versions of the spinner animation image in that DLL all cursors?

Comment: @Merlyn: Yes? I mean, is this a trick question? They're not .cur/.ani formatted files, they're PNGs. But the PNG was obviously generated by flattening the animated Aero busy cursor. Remember there are even multiple sizes of Aero cursors included with Vista/7. The point is that they *look* exactly the same, so using one or the other achieves exactly the same effect. My concern is trying to load them from the DLL is a risky proposition for a couple of reasons, namely that it will break on older versions of Windows (XP) and there's no guarantee they won't be moved/renumbered in the future.

Comment: @Cody: I asked because I don't know much about windows image resource file formats, or how cursors are formatted.  I figured that the different sized ones might be for icon usage, rather than cursor usage.  It occurred to me now that they included multiple formats for high DPI use.  Also, good point w/ XP compatibility.  He really should extract them.  If he wants to get really picky, he should also come up with something that fits in w/ XP theming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the images are available in %SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll

I used this application to browse that DLL, and manually verify that I saw the spinner animations:

http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm

See this question on how to insert these into your winforms application:

[How can I access to system icons like "folder", "file" etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605785/how-can-i-access-to-system-icons-like-folder-file-etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, - i did infact see the spinner animation using the program you suggested, but i couldn't quite figure out how to glean the loading image from the assembly. Will update question shortly with my efforts.